# How to rearrange the items of a QGridLayout according to an orientation?

Tags: c++, qt

On a QGridLayout arranged as in the picture below.

[image]

Suppose `this` is the `PushButton` at the top, how I could re-arrange it according to the `orientation`?

This is my attempt, but I'm struggling with how to properly rearrange the layout:

```cpp
    QGridLayout* gridLayout = qobject_cast<QGridLayout*>(parentWidget()->layout());
    gridLayout->removeWidget(this);
    
    switch (orientation)
    {
        case Orientation::LEFT:
            gridLayout->addWidget(this, 0, 0, gridLayout->rowCount(), 1);
            {
                QLayoutItem* item = gridLayout->itemAt(0);
                if (item)
                {
                    gridLayout->removeItem(item);
                    gridLayout->addItem(item, 0, gridLayout->columnCount(), gridLayout->rowCount(), 1);
                }
            }
            break;
    
        case Orientation::RIGHT:
            gridLayout->addWidget(this, 0, gridLayout->columnCount(), gridLayout->rowCount(), 1);
            break;
    
        case Orientation::BOTTOM:
            gridLayout->addWidget(this, gridLayout->rowCount(), 0, 1, gridLayout->columnCount());
            if (gridLayout->rowCount() == 2) 
            {
                // There are two items in the layout.
                // Move the bottom item to the top of the layout.
                QLayoutItem* item = gridLayout->itemAt(1);
                if (item) 
                {
                    gridLayout->removeItem(item);
                    gridLayout->addItem(item, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            break;
    
        default: // Default to TOP
            gridLayout->addWidget(this, 0, 0, 1, gridLayout->columnCount());
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Does "re-arrange it according to the `orientation`" mean placing it on top/right/bottom/left of the 2nd button? and in which method and when the user does what does this code gets triggered?

Comment: What about comparing their column and row in the grid? And is there any reason you're manipulating the layout from a child widget instead of the widget that actually has the layout? looks unusual to me. And I still would like to know, when does this code get triggered?

Comment: **item at (1,0)** is at the left side of **item at (1,1)** for example. And you should add that image to your question, it clarifies your question better.

Comment: If you don't have to use `QGridLayout`, why not use a `QBoxLayout`, put both of your widgets inside of it, and change its [Direction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qboxlayout.html#Direction-enum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I remove all layout items
2. I add layout items according to orientation

```
#include<QObject>
#include<QString>
#include<QMainWindow>
#include<QVBoxLayout>
#include<QTextEdit>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QEvent>
#include<QApplication>
#include<QDebug>
#include<QTextEdit>
#include<QGridLayout>

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    enum Orientation{LEFT, RIGHT
    , BOTTOM,};
    QWidget w;
    QGridLayout layout;
    QPushButton p1("1"), p2("2");
    layout.addWidget(&p1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    layout.addWidget(&p2, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    w.setLayout(&layout);
    auto func = [&](QPushButton* poButton, Orientation orientation)
    {
        QGridLayout* gridLayout = &layout;

        QLayoutItem* child;
        while ((child = gridLayout->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
            
                delete child;
        }



        switch (orientation)
        {
        case Orientation::LEFT:
            gridLayout->addWidget(&p1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            gridLayout->addWidget(&p2, 0, 1, 1, 1);
            break;

        case Orientation::RIGHT:
            gridLayout->addWidget(&p2, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            gridLayout->addWidget(&p1, 0, 1, 1, 1);
            break;

        case Orientation::BOTTOM:
            gridLayout->addWidget(&p1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
            gridLayout->addWidget(&p2, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            break;

        default: // Default to TOP

            gridLayout->addWidget(&p2, 1, 0, 1, 1);
            gridLayout->addWidget(&p1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            break;
        }
    };
    int ot = 0;
    QObject::connect(&p1, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {func(&p1, Orientation(ot++%4)); });
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `QGridLayout` can be replaced, it's much easier to use `QBoxLayout`, and just use its [setDirection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qboxlayout.html#setDirection) to move around the widgets in it.

Here's an example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;

    QBoxLayout *b = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom,&w);

    QPushButton *btn1 = new QPushButton(&w);
    btn1->setStyleSheet("background: red;");
    QPushButton *btn2 = new QPushButton("Moved Around Button",&w);
    btn2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    btn2->setStyleSheet("background: green;");

    QComboBox *comboBox = new QComboBox();
    comboBox->addItem("TOP");
    comboBox->addItem("RIGHT");
    comboBox->addItem("BOTTOM");
    comboBox->addItem("LEFT");

    QObject::connect(comboBox,&QComboBox::currentTextChanged,[=]()
    {
        if(comboBox->currentText()=="TOP")
        {
            //adjust the size as required            
            btn1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
            b->setDirection(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom);
        }
        if(comboBox->currentText()=="RIGHT")
        {
            btn1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
            b->setDirection(QBoxLayout::RightToLeft);
        }
        if(comboBox->currentText()=="BOTTOM")
        {
            btn1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Maximum);
            b->setDirection(QBoxLayout::BottomToTop);
        }
        if(comboBox->currentText()=="LEFT")
        {
            btn1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
            b->setDirection(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
        }
    });

    w.layout()->addWidget(btn1);
    w.layout()->addWidget(btn2);

    w.show();

    comboBox->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Result:

[image: 2 buttons in a box layout switching orientation]